# Flyway ERROR: No database found to handle jdbc:clickhouse://

Tags: sql-update, flyway, clickhouse

I am trying to use [Flyway](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd) for versioning a clickhouse database. My `flyway.conf` file looks like this:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:clickhouse://<host>:<port>/<database>?ssl=true
flyway.user=<user>
flyway.password=<password>
```

I want to use the CLI tool for using flyway, and I have a running docker image of fly way by executing the following commands (got it from [this tutorial](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/quickstart-docker-205226373.html))

```
docker pull redgate/flyway
docker run --rm redgate/flyway
```

After running the `docker run --rm -v <paths> redgate/flyway migrate`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: No database found to handle jdbc:clickhouse://<host>:<port>/<database>?ssl=true
```

SSL is required for my connection.

Based on this clickhouse documentation I know that there is a support for clickhouse in flyway but not sure how the `flyway.conf` setup should look like.

Answer (score 0):

So... it seems that you need more than just the clickhouse jdbc jar to do this (and there is an open PR for the flyway people: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/3611)

What I did:

1. Created a very simple pom.xml only to download all the clickhouse jdbc dependencies
2. Cloned (and builded it) the flyway's fork from the guy who created the clickhouse plugin (from here: https://github.com/sazonov/flyway/tree/clickhouse-support, note that the plugin is on branch "clickhouse-support")
3. Created a simple Dockerfile to add everything on the base flyway/flyway docker image:

- the dependencies from the driver (COPY to /flyway/drivers/ dir)
- the new jar file <cloned_dir>/flyway-community-db-support/target/flyway-community-db-support-*.jar (COPY to /flyway/lib/community/ dir)

After all that, I was able to make my migrations work on Clickhouse